# "a" or "an" in MSc

Tags: grammar, indefinite-articles

When I was writing out a degree title, I recall the "rule"

> "a" comes before a consonant
>   
>  "an" comes before a vowel

but then I naturally used to say that "I have an MSc degree" just for ease of pronunciation.

as M is a consonant, I thought this violates the "rule" but "an" is apparently the appropriate indefinite article for "MSc".

Why do I use "an" and not "a" ahead of a degree title as above?

Comment: Would you read that as "I have an em-es-cee degree" or "I have a Master of Science degree"?

Comment: When you recalled the rule, you left out one word. Sadly it was the most important word in the whole rule. The rule is, "*a* comes before a consonant *sound*, *an* comes before a vowel *sound*".

Comment: @KillingTime You are saying that the writer has complete freedom to choose here? In-house style guides may want to decide for acolytes.